# JavaScript Closure - method not recognized

Tags: javascript, closures, getter-setter

I am calling a function myFunc() and storing it in a variable myFunction passing 3 as a default argument that will be used to addition.

myFunction get the returned anonymous function with the parameter passed when logging message in the console.

I am also trying to access the method setValue of myFunction to change the original value of 3 to 1

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunc(numPassed){
            var num = numPassed;
            return function(x){
                setValue = function(newVal){
                    num = newVal;
                    return (num + x);
                };
            };
        }
        var myFunction = myFunc(3);
        myFunction.setValue(1);
        console.log(myFunction(4));
    </script>
```

**When I run this, it gives me the error:**

Object function (x) has no method 'setValue'

**I tried returning the setValue() as well but still the method is not being recognized.**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunc(numPassed){
            var num = numPassed;
            return function(x){
                return setValue = function(newVal){
                    num = newVal;
                    return (num + x);
                };
            };
        }
        var myFunction = myFunc(3);
        myFunction.setValue(1);
        console.log(myFunction(4));
    </script>
```

Comment: You are not returning the funtion 'setValue' and cant call it

Comment: I edited my post and returning the setValue(). I still get the same error message.

Comment: What are you intending this code to do?  It looks like you're expecting two input parameters somehow (x and newVal), but you're only ever supplying one in example usage.

Comment: I have edited my post for description at the top

Comment: It's still not clear where you're providing a value for `x`. Why does `setValue` return the sum of `num` and `x`? Your code seems to want to do more than what is described in the question.

Comment: if you go over the code carefully, you would understand why I'm providing a value for x - to add num and x and return the added value

Comment: You're **not** providing a value for `x`.

Comment: I am with this - console.log(myFunction(4));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you'd like `myFunc` to create a function which will add its input `x` to the value `numPassed`, but allow `numPassed` to be overridden at a later time using `setValue`.  If that's the case, your code should look like this:

```
function myFunc(numPassed){
    var num = numPassed;
    function add(x) {
        return num + x;
    };
    add.setValue = function(newVal) {
        num = newVal;
    };
    return add;
}
```

Since `myFunc` returns `add`, everything that you want to publicly accessible from the return value must be a property of `add`.

Comment: This did it and I got what I was doing wrong. Thanks.